# Что происходит при выделения памяти под объект класса?

Tags: c++

Допустим, есть у меня класс BaseA. У него есть виртуальные и статические методы, а так же конструктор с деструктором.
Когда я делаю выделение памяти `BaseA *a = new BaseA();`, как я понимаю создаётся таблица виртуальных методов, в которую записываются все виртуальные функции класса. Туда же, как я понял, записывается и конструктор по-умолчанию.
А куда записываются статические методы, деструктор и другие конструкторы?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых эта таблица это всего лишь указатель `vptr` на статический массив из указателей на функции, поэтому туда только указатели на функции и будут ... а не "сами функции".

Статические методы это глобальные для данного класса функции, которые доступны всем через идентификатор класса `Base::MyStaticMethod();` - следовательно их не имеет смысла записывать в эту таблицу.

А указатели на деструкторы должны будут оказаться в этой таблице, иначе, например, деструктор производного класса не вызывался бы при удалении объекта через указатель на базовый - т.е. в такой ситуации

```
Base* bp = new Derived();
delete bp;
```

произошла бы утечка памяти

Comment: Так что, статические методы вообще никуда не записываются?

Comment: @andrew что значит вобще никуда не записываются? неправильно вобще говорить что функция куда то "записывается" я же написал что только указатели хранятся

Comment: @andrew тоесть, нет, указатели на статические функции в таблицу (в этот массив) не записываются

Comment: Про указатели на конструкторы - чушь

Comment: @int3 эм, нуда, конструкторы виртуальными не бывают, следовательно его указатель не будет в таблице, но будет где-то в другом месте

Comment: @int3 исправил ответ

Comment: @ampawd и в других местах его не будет. Конструктор всегда вызывается явно, как и статические/невиртуальные методы

Comment: @int3 ну указатель на конструктор все равно создаётся, только получить его компилятор не позволит скорее всего

Comment: @ampawd указатель - это адрес, лежащий в некоторой области памяти. Сам конструктор создаётся и имеет адрес, но этот адрес нигде не сохранён и присутствует только во время компиляции. Другое дело -
 насильно сохранить его в переменную - отдельный вопрос

Comment: @int3 ну вот насильно сохранить в переменную как раз такие и не получится

Answer (score 1):

Таблица создается еще при компиляции. При создании объекта в него добавляется указатель на эту таблицу (одну для всех объектов данного класса).

Невиртуальные методы никуда не "записываются", так как еще на этапе компиляции известно, когда они вызываются, так что выполняется просто вызов указанного метода. Например, куда записывается, ну, скажем, функция `sin` или `printf`? Вот туда же записываются и невиртуальные методы...